# What's this font please?

Tags: typefaces

[image]

Can anyone help with this font name? Thanks

Comment: This is the custom tuscan style font of the Boston Red Sox, used here as a logotype. Im unsure what the name is, mainly because it was likely designed specifically for the MLB team. You can get free similar ones out there but they wont be identical.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a font, it's a custom hand-drawn [logotype.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos_and_uniforms_of_the_Boston_Red_Sox)

Answer (score 0):

It is a **Victorian** or **Tuscan Style** typography. Search on Google for *Ornamented Tuscan font*.

I didn't find it as a font but as a specimen of a [Wood Type Catalog](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-85959.html): Tuscan Ornamented nº 1

[image]