# What is this "circled G" glyph alongside Greek text in an English book from 1765?

Tags: typesetting, book, history, ligatures

From Thomas Edwards' [*The Canons of Criticism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rqhVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA271), printed by C. Bathurst (1765) in London, in a font that (as you can see) has long-S and c-t ligatures:

[image: Page 271]

The text centered in this image says:

> of Nat. Bailey, *φιλολογⒼ*: A horny induration of

What on earth is that "circled G" glyph that I've rendered "Ⓖ" above?
I suppose that it was meant to represent *-ος*, as in *φιλολογος* "philologist"; my curiosity is entirely about the typographical aspect.

- Was this glyph (whatever it is) correctly used, here? Is it some Greek ligature I haven't seen before?
- (More likely) Was this just a printer's error? I could imagine the sequence of handwritten characters "ος" being misinterpreted as "circle, G." But then, how did the printer come to possess a piece of type for this "Ⓖ" glyph already? What is the *intended* use for this glyph, and where else would I find it used?
- Except for the circle, it looks a bit like an "et" ligature (ampersand); is that relevant?

Comment: This seems to be more of language (or history) question than a graphic design question. But.. I can see the logic in posting it here.

Comment: @Scott: It’s a bit hard to say without knowing the answer. If it’s a historic typesetting convention, I would consider it on-topic here. It’s arguably also on-topic on [history.se] and I would guess it’s more likely to get an answer there – but I may also be wrong about that. It may also be that [latin.se] and [english.se] are best. It’s one of those questions that falls right in to the crack between the scopes of several sites and makes you wish for a way to have true cross-posts.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: [Meta says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260057/site-for-typography-question) Graphic Design is the right place for typography questions. I've had good luck in the past, e.g. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117804/what-is-the-name-for-these-serif-like-features-of-stereotypical-old-west-lette . I'm glad there's no "Typography Stack Exchange": it would get so little traffic. I just wish people would stop the reflexive "_I_ don't like typography so downvote/close to get this typography junk off _my_ site." The site's big enough for all of us to share!

Comment: It was not my intent to imply this question is completely out in left field for this stack. Not at all. I merely felt there may be other stacks with users more knowledgeable in ancient text and typography glyphs, that's all.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It appears to be an omicron-sigma ligature that was used in early Greek printing. I have no idea if it is still in use.

This image is from the [Wikipedia page on Greek ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_ligatures)

[image]

Another example here from [Text Creation Partnership](https://textcreationpartnership.org/docs/dox/greek.html). Several examples appear on that page. These all seem to be dated around the 16th century.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As said above, it essentially is an ο and ς (σ) together. The word is "φιλολογος" in modern Greek, this just merges the two letters together. I don't recall having seen it used in anything recent.

Source : am Greek.

Comment: That's a pretty good source... :-)

Comment: Only one I got :)